# Coq: Create a super-type of boolean and nat

Tags: types, coq, mixed

I want to create a list of mixed types of `boolean` and `nat`. This list must hold elements of some super-type: `boat` where every `boolean` is a `boat` and every `nat` is a `boat`.

The problem I am having is that this super-type `boat` should have a `boat_eq_dec` meaning there should be a way to decide whether two `boat`'s are the same or different. As `nat` and `boolean` both have such an equality decider, the super-type should have one as well.

In the example below, I have created a super-type, but I cannot show the equality-deciding lemma`Lemma boat_eq_dec : forall x y : Boat, {x = y} + {x <> y}.`

```
Inductive Boat : Set :=
  | is_bool (inp: bool)
  | is_nat (inp: nat).
```

What is the correct way to define this super-type, or show the lemma?

Comment: The definition of `Boat` looks fine to me, and it's possible (if slightly cheating) to get `boat_eq_dec` using [`Scheme Equality for Boat.`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/user-extensions/proof-schemes.html#coq:cmdv.scheme-equality).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also directly use `(bool + nat)%type` (using `sum`) to get a general notion. 
Then `decide equality` can solve several *`eq_dec`* goals.

```
Definition boat := (bool + nat)%type.

Lemma boat_eq_dec :
  forall x y : boat, {x = y} + {x <> y} .
Proof.
  intros x y. decide equality.
  all: decide equality.
Defined.
```

You could even consider proving the general lemma

```
forall A B,
  (forall x y : A, {x = y} + {x <> y}) ->
  (forall x y : B, {x = y} + {x <> y}) ->
  forall x y : A + B, {x = y} + {x <> y}.
```

It is already proved in the `Equations` library, but it's probably not worth installing just for this.

Comment: Cool! Thank you!
After a bit of fiddling I got to instantiate some variable of your type as well:
`Definition test_boat_list : list boat := (inr 1) :: (inl true) :: nil.`

Comment: Ah yes sorry for not saying. The way to go usually is to type `Print sum.` so that you know how to instantiate it.